# Rc.local not running commands properly

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, arch-linux, executable

I am running arch Linux and have used this rc-local service:

```
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local compatibility

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is my rc.local:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
iwconfig wlp6s0 frag 256
iwconfig wlp6s0 rts 256
iwconfig wlp6s0 retry 7
exit 0
```

The only command that gets run is the retry one. I can see this using the output of `sudo iwconfig` which returns:

```
wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Hoersdal 5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 54:A0:50:5B:C2:34   
          Bit Rate=117 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

How do I fix this ?
BTW I have made it executable by using `sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local`

Comment: Could it be the interface is not yet fully configured in the first commands? Try to run an iwconfig redirected to a file as the first command to test it out.

Comment: It didn't output to a file even though I tried. Why might this actually be the answer and how do I fix it.

Comment: Would you mind redirecting the stderr too and trying again? (I am not ignoring the rest of your question, it just might be easier answering it in one go it stderr confirms my suspicion)

Comment: Still nothing sadly.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely trying to run the commands and failing because the `iwconfig` executable can't be found - because there's no `$PATH` variable available. You should always use absolute pathnames in cron scripts and similar and not rely on a `$PATH` setting that might not be there.

Comment: ExecStart has an absolute value.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the `retry` line worked.

Comment: Yeah, I'm quite confused about that.

Comment: John it didn't work, I used /bin/iwconfig instead and it still didn't work. I didn't think so in the first place though because it did execute one of the commands.